# Powershell Script for taking Farm backup in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, server-farm

Is there any ready made farm backup script available?I want to take the backup of my SP 2013 farm which has 2 WFEs,1 Index server and 1 Sql Server. I want to take the complete content residing in the content databases/site collections.

Comment: In PowerShell command try passing folder path like this `\\YourComputerName\YourShareDirName`

Comment: Thanks Asad for the help. I added the  foldername without bak file and its started taking the backup. Its still in progress. Will update here once its complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command below always helped me to take backup of entire farm.

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory C:\Backup -BackupMethod full -BackupThreads 10 -Force
```

Source: [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428316.aspx) and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607881.aspx)

If you want a script which will take backup regularly, I'll suggest you to check [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/9b99c435-8831-4c9e-a70b-1f13158ef22a). It's for SharePoint 2010 but I don't see any reason for it to not work with SharePoint 2013, though please check once.

**Note:** Backup-SPFarm command use a network share drive so please make sure that the service accounts, Farm accounts and SQL Server service accounts have Full Control access to the share drive.

Comment: but i am getting the error Directory D:\backup\142Farm_Backup\SPFarmBackup_26-Jun-2015-11-01-45 does not exist or the SQL Server service account and the domainn\myuser1 service 
account do not have permission to read or write to the backup folder. Specify a different directory or ensure that the SharePoint Timer service and Microsoft SQL Server 
service accounts have Full Control permission on both the file share and the underlying folder.
At line:15 char:1

Comment: Please read my Note. You need to provide full control on the share drive.

Comment: Thanks. I have added a "myback.bak" file which is not required. I just needed to mention the  folder name only.